# Deploy ReactJS application on CentOS 7 server using Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, centos7, neo4j-apoc

I have deployed a ReactJS (with neo4j database) application on CentOS 7 server. I want to deploy another instance of the same application on the same server using docker. I have installed docker (version 20.10.12) on the server (CentOS 7).

On the server, I have cloned my reactjs project and created following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16 as builder
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM httpd:alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY --from=builder /app/build/ .
```

and following docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  app-test:
    hostname: my-app-test.com
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    command: nohup node server.js &
    networks:
      - app-test-network
  app-test-neo4j:
    image: neo4j:4.4.2
    ports:
      - '7474:7474'
      - '7473:7473'
      - '7687:7687'
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/neo4j/data:/data
      - ./volumes/neo4j/conf:/conf
      - ./volumes/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
      - ./volumes/neo4j/logs:/logs
      - ./volumes/neo4j/import:/import
      - ./volumes/neo4j/init:/init
    networks:
      - app-test-network
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo/password
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.*
      - NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_whitelist=apoc.*
      - NEO4J_dbms_default__listen__address=0.0.0.0
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7687
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7474
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address=:7687
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address=:7474
      - NEO4J_dbms_default__database=neo4j
      - NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=["apoc"]
      - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true
      - NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled=true
      - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config=true
      - NEO4J_dbms_shell_enabled=true
networks:
  app-test-network:
    driver: bridge
```

But, after running docker-compose up , i get following error:

```
ERROR: for app-repo_app-test Cannot start service app-test: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint app-repo_app-test (2cffe4fa4299d6e53a784f7f564dfa49d1a2cb82e4b599391b2a3206563d0e47): ErroCreating app-repo_app-test-neo4j ... done

ERROR: for app-test  Cannot start service app-test: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint app-repo_app-test (2cffe4fa4299d6e53a784f7f564dfa49d1a2cb82e4b599391b2a3206563d0e47): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Can anyone give me any clue what went wrong here ? And, is it the correct approach to deploy the reactjs application on CentOS 7 server using Docker ?

Comment: You should check this out https://medium.com/@hendrikwallbaum/dockerizing-spas-9f72b7867e41

Comment: @Ali Hussnain, thank you for the link. any clue to fix the error ?

Comment: Try not to use hyphen in the resource name, I would say use small or caps letter.

Comment: @Ali Hussnain , I edited the Dockerfile, but got another error. please check my update

Comment: @Ali Hussnain, If i use FROM node:16 , how to copy the build files (the last line of the Dockerfile) into the apache root folder ?

Comment: You can copy using `COPY --from=Resource Name . .`

Comment: @Ali Hussnain what will be the 'Resource Name' here ? node:16 ? how to define the last line of the Dockerfile ?

Comment: Are you sure /app/build exists in the Container?

Comment: @BertC , not sure. i am new in docker. btw when we run 'npm run build ' , won't it create a build folder ?

Comment: Sorry for the misconfusion from my end. The problem looks like you create a new container from httpd:alpine. But you should extend the previous container.

Comment: @BertC so the last line in Dockerfile should be like this ?  'COPY . /app/build/ . '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said in my comment above: You are not using the first container in the Multi-Stage container.

See this article: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#name-your-build-stages

And particularly the example code:

```yaml
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM golang:1.16 AS builder
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go    ./
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app ./
CMD ["./app"]
```

The **COPY --from=builder** will do the trick for you.

Comment: I tried similar approach before, but it showed following error:   
"Step 1/10 : FROM node:16 as build-stage
ERROR: Service 'app-test' failed to build: Error parsing reference: "node:16 as build-stage" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format"

Comment: I guess "build-stage" is not a valid repository tag. Try "builder" or "buildstage".

Comment: getting same error : 
"Step 1/10 : FROM node:16 as builder
ERROR: Service 'app-test' failed to build: Error parsing reference: "node:16 as builder" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
"

Comment: Can you post the new Dockerfile?

Comment: "
FROM node:16 as builder
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM httpd:alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY --from=builder /app/build/ .
"

Comment: Uuh, in another answer please, then I see the line break, can copy/paste is on my macbook and try it out myself. :-)

Comment: please check the updated question

Comment: Ok, that looks good. If this does not work do the following to investigate: 1) Take away the last FROM in the Dockerfile. 2) Add a 'command' to the compose file with a sleep command  (command: ["sleep", "100d"]  3) start the container and go into the container. Then check if /app/build is there and work on the problem from there.

Comment: Can you write your suggested Dockerfile and compose file in your answer please ?

Comment: Docker 1.13 is pretty ancient at this point and it doesn't support the `FROM image AS name` multi-stage build syntax.  Upgrade your Docker, or better, build the image somewhere other than the production server.

Comment: @David Maze I upgraded Docker version and the error was gone. But i got another error which is posted above. please check the updated question

Comment: Please don't rewrite your question to be something completely different.  I'd suggest reverting your edit so this answer makes sense.  Please do search Stack Overflow for the new error you're getting before you ask a new question.

Comment: @David Maze Docker is working and the application is started after 'docker-compose up'. But I can't access the application from the browser. it seems docker is not linked with virtualhost. Do i need to install CentOS before installing node and httpd in the Dockerfile ?

Comment: Agree with @DavidMaze, If you have a new problem, please create a new Post. Now it's getting confusing. Preferably create a full example on public github which can be downloaded. Then you make it easy for other people to help you.